# Ошибка flatMap is not a function

Tags: javascript

Прохожу курс по js на coursera. При проверке стандартным checks.js возникла ошибка -
"(имя функции).flatMap is not a function"
Сам код стабильно работает в браузере, а переписать код как то по другому у меня не хватает мозгов)

Сам код

```
/**
 * @param {String} tweet
 * @returns {String[]}
 */
module.exports = function (tweet) {
  let words = tweet.flatMap(sentence => sentence.split(' '));
  let result = words.filter(word => word.startsWith('#'));
  preresult = result.map((v) => v.slice(1, 30));
  return preresult
};
```

cheaks.js -

```
// Встроенный в Node.JS модуль для проверок
var assert = require('assert');

// Подключаем свою функцию
var getHashTags = require('./index.js');

assert.deepEqual(
    getHashTags('Прохожу курс на #coursera по #javascript'),
    ['coursera', 'javascript'],
    'Строка "Прохожу курс на #coursera по #javascript"' +
    ' должна содержать хэштеги "coursera, javascript"'
);

console.info('OK!');
```

Comment: в данном случае flatMap не нужен, вызывай сразу split: `let words = tweet.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap` это метод массива, а вы пытаетесь передать строку

```
getHashTags('Прохожу курс на #coursera по #javascript')
```

а у строк нет функции `flatMap`. В прошлом примере вы ведь писали функцию для массива:

```
const arrTweets = [
  'Попробывал твитнуть',
  'Я уже совсем #обтвитовался',
  "Не #могу ничего #твинтнуть",
];
const lol = arrTweets.flatMap(sentence => sentence.split(' '));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все тесты прошли на ура. Правда в сервисе все равно не один тест не проходится((